# Is it possible to generate a video with pure JavaScript just like html2canvas can generate an image?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I want to develop a page that can have a "record" button on it. When the user clicks the button, it will record everything happening on the page, and when I click "stop", it will generate a video and let the user save it.

Is it possible to do that without any server-side technology?

Comment: not sure it's possible with server side code at all

Comment: https://github.com/yaronn/GifW00t

Answer (score 2):

You can check out [Screen Capture API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture), if that is what you are looking for.